# Django: Accessing ForeignKey fields and creating new relations based on them

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I'm fairly new to Django I'm trying to build a multichat app using Django 2.0.5 and my models are the following:

```
class DateTimeModel(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Room(DateTimeModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        ...

class Message(DateTimeModel):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        ...
```

**What I want to do**: I want to set the database scheme such that each message knows who its recipients are in the room that it belongs to and somehow stores whether each member in that room has 'seen' the message. I am having a tough time trying to see how I could make it work.

Thanks in advance!
Ahmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get message recipients, use (for example if we have a message in the database, with id=1)

```
message = Message.objects.get(pk=1)
recipients = message.room.members
```

For the part where you said you would want to see who has seen the message. Use the following method(it's not the only way, but an example):

Add another field to your `Message` model which would be `ManyToMany` field.
Maybe like `seen = models.ManyToManyField(User)` Such that when you catch the event, maybe when a user clicks on the message, send a post/get request to the server, notifying it of a seen event and there you use the following code:

```
message = Message.objects.get(id=POST_DATA['message_id'])
user = request.user
if user not in message.seen:
   message.seen.add(user)
'''
continue with app logic
'''
```

I hope you got an idea.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted for now. With this, my idea about ForeignKey and ManytoMany relationships are also cleared up a little bit.